# What were CO2 levels in Carboniferous?

Tags: atmosphere, paleoclimatology

What were CO2 levels in early and late Carboniferous, an what were mean levels? Who are the sources for these figures?

Comment: related https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10114/did-climate-cool-down-when-underground-hydrocarbons-stocks-formed

Comment: What do you mean under "who are the sources"? Do you mean who are these researchers who came up with these estimates, or do you mean what is the scientific basis for these estimations?

Comment: I have read that the Carboniferous was caused by the evolution of plant cellulose or lignin and fibres, and it took millions of years for microbes and animals and funghi to develop enzymes to dissolve it so it caused excess oxygen. Perhaps the co2 was caused by fires.

Answer (score 1):

Carboniferous CO<sub>2</sub> levels may not have been unlike today's. Evidence for this is primarily from long term geochemical modeling work, as there are few direct proxies of sufficient age.

I can easily cite one source, as it's from my own paper, but please check the reference list for the other datasets. http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chemgeo.2013.10.012
[image: Phanerozoic CO2, fig. 5, p. 294]